# А как называется тег из html

Tags: javascript, html, css

Как называется этот выбор чисел на фото[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: select? ........

Comment: http://htmlbook.ru/html/select

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Это селект :)

```html
<select name="nums" id="qqqq">
    <option value="one">1</option>
    <option value="two">2</option>
    <option value="three">3</option>
</select>
```

Comment: Спасибо) огромное

Answer (score 3):

Как вам уже указали, что это `select`. Но, коли, возникают такие вопросы, то вот вам способ как посмотреть тот или иной элемент.

**Пример для Chrome**

Просто на странице выберите элемент и щелкните правой кнопкой мыши (или <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>i</kbd>) -> затем выберите `Inspect`.
Справа открывается окно, где вы и можете подсмотреть тот или иной элемент.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

То же самое можно провернуть в любом другом браузере.